# How can I filter an email domain that is a property of an object that is in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array

```
let registers = [Register, Register, Register];
```

and

```
Register {name: 'Ray', email: 'ray@gmail.com', password: '1234'}
Register {name: 'Carl', email: 'carl@gmail.com', password: '4321'}
Register {name: 'Lina', email: 'lina@outlook.com', password: '5678'}
```

How can I get a new array with the objects that have @gmail.com as email ?

Comment: array.filter(el => el.email.includes('@gmail.com'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

`Array.filter` filters the original array with some condition, where `String.includes` provides the condition, the email includes a string `@gmail.com`

```js
const data = [{ name: 'Ray', email: 'ray@gmail.com', password: '1234' },
              { name: 'Carl', email: 'carl@gmail.com', password: '4321' },
              { name: 'Lina', email: 'lina@outlook.com', password: '5678' }];

const output = data.filter(node => node.email.includes('@gmail.com'));;

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and regex here `/@gmail\.com$/` to get only the elements that ends with `gmail.com`

[image]

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Ray", email: "ray@gmail.com", password: "1234" },
  { name: "Carl", email: "carl@gmail.com", password: "4321" },
  { name: "Lina", email: "lina@outlook.com", password: "5678" },
];

const output = data.filter((o) => o.email.match(/@gmail\.com$/));

console.log(output);
```